# Nginx - Redirect Domain Trailing Dot

Tags: nginx

How can I redirect "http://domain.com." to "http://domain.com" with Nginx?

What's the recommended way of doing this? Regex or is there any other options?

Comment: see this post about danger of trailing dot in domain: http://saynt2day.blogspot.com/2013/03/danger-of-trailing-dot-in-domain-name.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following snippet does this in a general way, without having to hard code any hostnames (useful if your server config handles requests for multiple domains).  Add this inside any server definition that you need to.

```
if ($http_host ~ "\.$" ){
    rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact (pointed out by [Igor Sysoev](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163942)) that `$host` has the trailing dot removed, while `$http_host` doesn't; so we can match the dot in `$http_host` and automatically use `$host` for the redirect.

Comment: Use `rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host$1 permanent;` to get rid of hardcoded scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesion (and edit) @SlavaFominII - much better.

Comment: In the 1.10 Nginx, the trailing dot is not in the $host or $http_host.

Comment: I did not test Nginx 1.10, but using [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45363247/25507), I tested 1.18, and `$http_host` still includes the trailing dot, so this solution should still work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Regex.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com.WHATEVER, domain.com.WHATEVER-2, domain.com.WHATEVER-3;
    rewrite  ^  $scheme://domain.com$request_uri?  permanent;
}
```

From: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule

redirect - returns temporary redirect with code 302; it is used if the substituting line begins with http://
permanent - returns permanent redirect with code 301