# nginx accepts trailing dot when server_name regex does not match

Tags: nginx

Nginx accepts trailing dot (e.g. `example.tld.`). The regex has set start and end of `server_name`, see bellow.

```
server_name ~^example.tld$;
```

The `server_name` regex does not match `example.tld.` but nginx matches this vhost. I have found [this question about redirecting trailing dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452328/nginx-redirect-domain-trailing-dot) question but it is something like workaround, isn't it?

I wonder **why nginx matches vhost even while the regex does not match**? Is it some kind of internal logic based on RFC standards?

Comment: If my answer answers the question, any chance to get a +1, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe it stems from the trailing dot being the standard DNS notation that signifies a fully-qualified-domain-name (FQDN).  In a BIND-compatible zone file, any name without a trailing dot is relative to `$ORIGIN`.

Similarly, the same goes for [`resolv.conf`](http://mdoc.su/n/resolv.conf), where, if it contains `search online.net`, then instead of going to `console.online.net.`, you can simply go to just `console` (OTOH, going to `console.` won't work, as such root zone doesn't currently exist (I know — I was actually very surprised myself that no registry has taken up such an awesome TLD zone yet ^_^ — although even if it did exist, it'll likely not have an `A` record anyways)).

As such, the trailing dot is automatically removed from the string that is deemed to be the host, as per [nginx server name regex when "Host" header has a trailing dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363246/nginx-server-name-regex-when-host-header-has-a-trailing-dot/45363247#45363247), which, for correctness and completeness sake, must happen prior to the execution of the regex within the context of the `server_name` directive, hence, the trailing dot will never match.