# nginx server name regex when "Host" header has a trailing dot

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, httprequest

I've considered [potential trailing hostname dot handling in two contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357325/nginx-wildcard-rewrite-in-same-server-block/45359134#45359134) in nginx, and was curious whether usage in either one is necessary for an entirely correct configuration:

- `server_name ~^(\w+)\.(example\.com)\.?$;`
- `if ($host ~ ^(\w*)\.(example\.com)\.?$) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary in either context — nginx automatically takes care of the trailing dot, both in the context of the [`$host` variable](http://nginx.org/r/$host), as well as the [`server_name` directive](http://nginx.org/r/server_name), leaving only the [`$http_host` variable](http://nginx.org/r/$http_host) with the extra dot (if present in the request).

I believe it is implemented in [`http/ngx_http_request.c#ngx_http_validate_host`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_request.c#ngx_http_validate_host):

```
1925    if (dot_pos == host_len - 1) {
1926        host_len--;
1927    }
```

It can be verified with the following minimal config:

```
server {
    listen  [::]:7325;
    server_name ~^(\w*)\.?(example\.com\.?)$;
    return  200 C:$2\tH:$host\tHH:$http_host\tSN:$server_name\n;
}
```

Running the following tests against `nginx/1.2.1`:

```
%printf 'GET / HTTP/1.0\nHost: head.example.com.\n\n' | nc localhost 7325 | fgrep example
C:example.com   H:head.example.com  HH:head.example.com.    SN:~^(\w*)\.?(example\.com\.?)$
%
%printf 'GET http://line.example.com./ HTTP/1.0\n\n' | nc localhost 7325 | fgrep example
C:example.com   H:line.example.com  HH: SN:~^(\w*)\.?(example\.com\.?)$
%
%printf 'GET http://line.example.com./ HTTP/1.0\nHost: head.example.com.\n\n' | nc localhost 7325 | fgrep example
C:example.com   H:line.example.com  HH:head.example.com.    SN:~^(\w*)\.?(example\.com\.?)$
%
```

Note that neither the regexp capture from within the `server_name` directive, nor the `$host` variable, ever has a trailing dot.  As such, it is pointless to account for it in above contexts.